# KuCoin Nonce Calculation

Tags: nonce

I am having a very hard time calculating a nonce to connect to the KuCoin Exchange. I am currently using the following code to calculate the nonce in C#:

```
long nonce = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> "{\"code\":\"UNAUTH\",\"msg\":\"Invalid nonce\",\"success\":false,\"timestamp\":1539429475443}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kucoin documentation doesn't explicitly state that it wants the value in unix time. DateTime.Ticks in .net is based on 1st January in year 1, whilst the unix epoch is on 1st January 1970.

you can use this code to get the value you need:

`var CurrentTimestamp = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds`

Answer (score 2):

According to https://kucoinapidocs.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/authentication the Kucoin API wants the nonce to be a timestamp expressed in milliseconds.

However, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2 says that `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` represents time in "ticks", where a tick is a tenth of a microsecond.

That means that there are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, so to convert the `.Ticks` result to the millisecond value that Kucoin wants you must divide it by 10,000:

```
long nonce = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / 10000;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the provided answer still gives the same error message.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that the starting time (the "epoch") for `DateTime.UtcNow` was different too.  I'm glad the other answerer did notice.